# How to stop specific function when another function is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, timer, pyqt

If i click `pushButton_1` it displays correctly, and then if `pushButton_2` is clicked.
Both functions are running simultaneously and overlapping each other.

> self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.fun)

```
def fun(self):
    print("1...")
    #for grabbing live data from excelsheet
    timer = threading.Timer(5.0, self.fun)
    timer.start()

     #reading from sheet1; ignore sheet_name=2        
    ex_data = pd.read_excel('bank2.xlsm',sheet_name=2,skiprows=5, nrows=18, 
                             usecols = 'D:V')
    df = pd.DataFrame(ex_data)
    df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(df.index))


    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iloc[i, 
                                      j])))
            self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

> self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.fun2)

```
def fun2(self):
    print("2...")
    timer = threading.Timer(5.0, self.fun2)
    timer.start()
    ex_data = pd.read_excel('bank2.xlsm',sheet_name=3,skiprows=5, nrows=18, 
                             usecols = 'D:V')
    df = pd.DataFrame(ex_data)
    df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(df.index))
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,QTableWidgetItem(str(df.iloc[i, 
                                      j])))
            self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

So, i am working in PyQt5 project, when `pushButton_1` is pressed it should display live data from excel file for which i had to implement `Timer` for live update.
Same for second button.
I want `fun` to stop executing, whenever `fun2` is called. Vice versa

Comment: Use a `QThread` that runs forever and change with `button1/button2` only the `data` to display.

Comment: @eyllanesc here's the example https://pastebin.com/vVJH4xwv   as you can see both are overlaping each other.

Comment: @ClaWnN Important information such as the code should be in your question, so if you want help put the code in your question

Comment: @eyllanesc should i edit this post, or make new one?

Comment: @ClaWnN edit your question. Read [ask] and review the [tour]